# create a filter variable to indicate time order value is available in r

Tags: r, filter

I have student scores and some students take multiple scores with time order. Here is the sample dataset I have.

```
df <- data.frame(
         id =   c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6),
         time = c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1),
         score = c(15,16,18,19,22,29,19,52))

> df
  id time score
1  1    1    15
2  2    1    16
3  2    2    18
4  3    1    19
5  4    1    22
6  5    1    29
7  5    2    19
8  6    1    52
```

`time` variable here is actual time but I just put number order for simplicity. I need flag variables to show which students took first and which took the second score.

Here is my desired output.

```
> df
  id time score  score1 score2
1  1    1    15    1      0
2  2    1    16    1      0
3  2    2    18    0      1
4  3    1    19    1      0
5  4    1    22    1      0
6  5    1    29    1      0
7  5    2    19    0      1
8  6    1    52    1      0
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(score1 = case_when(time == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0), 
              score2 = case_when(time == 2 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
  id time score score1 score2
1  1    1    15      1      0
2  2    1    16      1      0
3  2    2    18      0      1
4  3    1    19      1      0
5  4    1    22      1      0
6  5    1    29      1      0
7  5    2    19      0      1
8  6    1    52      1      0
```